# What is shortest in code terms way for given N to output strings "1", "1 2"... "1 2 ... N"?

Tags: c#, linq, enumerable

What is shortest in code terms way for given N (int) to output `List<strings> out;` containing strings `"1", "1 2"... "1 2 ... N"`? For N == 3 `out` would contain "1"; "1 2"; "1 2 3"

Comment: Show or tell us what have you tried and what problem do you have as SO is not "write me some code" portal.

Comment: It's very hard to be sure of such a thing as having reached the shortest possible code.

Comment: I suggest writing a method that does what you want, and naming it `A`. The shortest possible call to get the desired results will then be `A();`.

Comment: Try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, n)
          .Select(i => String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, i)))
          .ToList();
```

For n = 3 produces:

```
[
  "1",
  "1 2",
  "1 2 3"
]
```

Comment: Sorry all, I understand that question is of low-quality, but it was interesting to try